# train_test_split exception with 2D labels as stratify array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, train-test-split

I'm trying to use the `train_test_split` function by providing the labels array that is a 2-d array for stratifying, with only 0 or 1 values (i.e. [0,0], [0,1], [1,0] or [1,1] are the four possible labels). I cannot rename labels (e.g. to 1,2,3,4 for instance) for code compatibility reasons.

Hereafter the code of the function where  `train_test_split` is used

```
def preprocess_csv_deceptive_opinion(path, prediction, dataset_recreations):
"""

:param path: path of the original csv file
:param prediction: it can be 'deceptive', 'polarity' or both on the basis of what you want to predict
:param dataset_recreations: it is the number of random seeds used
:return:
"""

read_dataset = pd.read_csv(path)  # Dataset columns: deceptive,hotel,polarity,source,text

# print('average sentence length: ', df.text.str.split().str.len().mean())
# print('stdev sentence length: ', df.text.str.split().str.len().std())

read_dataset = read_dataset.drop(['hotel', 'source'], axis=1)

if prediction == 'multi':
    # 00 = truthful positive, 01 = truthful negative, 10 = deceptive positive, 11 = deceptive negative
    read_dataset['deceptive'] = (read_dataset['deceptive'] == 'deceptive').astype(int)
    read_dataset['polarity'] = (read_dataset['polarity'] == 'negative').astype(int)
elif prediction == 'deceptive':
    read_dataset = read_dataset.drop(['polarity'], axis=1)                          # 0 = truthful, 1 = deceptive
    read_dataset['deceptive'] = (read_dataset['deceptive'] == 'deceptive').astype(int)
elif prediction == 'polarity':
    read_dataset = read_dataset.drop(['deceptive'], axis=1)
    read_dataset['polarity'] = (read_dataset['polarity'] == 'negative').astype(int) # 0 = positive, 1 = negative
else:
    sys.exit('Label not valid!')

cols = read_dataset.columns

if prediction == 'multi':
    label_cols = list(cols[:2])
elif prediction == 'deceptive' or prediction == 'polarity':
    label_cols = list(cols[:1])
else:
    sys.exit('"label_cols" variable not initialised!')

num_labels = len(label_cols)
print('Label columns: ', label_cols)

read_dataset['one_hot_labels'] = list(read_dataset[label_cols].to_numpy())

# def get_scalar(x):
#     if (x == [0, 0]).all():
#         return 0    # truthful positive
#     elif (x == [0, 1]).all():
#         return 1    # truthful negative
#     elif (x == [1, 0]).all():
#         return 2    # deceptive positive
#     elif (x == [1, 1]).all():
#         return 3    # deceptive negative

# if prediction == 'multi':
#     read_dataset['one_hot_labels'] = list(map(get_scalar, read_dataset['one_hot_labels']))
read_dataset = read_dataset.drop(['deceptive', 'polarity'], axis=1)

# read_dataset = read_dataset.drop(['deceptive', 'polarity'], axis=1)

# Resulting dataset: x | text | one_hot_labels where:
# x is deceptive or polarity or [deceptive, polarity] where get_scalar function is applied to the latest alternative
# one_hot_labels is [deceptive] or [polarity] or [deceptive, polarity]

training_sizes = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

training_data = {}
validation_data = {}
for size in training_sizes:
    training_data[size] = {}
    validation_data[size] = {}
    for i in range(dataset_recreations):
        print(type(read_dataset.one_hot_labels))
        training, validation = train_test_split(read_dataset, train_size=size, shuffle=True, random_state=i, stratify=read_dataset['one_hot_labels'].to_numpy())
        training_data[size][i] = training
        validation_data[size][i] = validation

return [read_dataset, num_labels, training_data, validation_data]
```

But I receive the following:

```
File "/home/[...]/main.py", line 1409, in preprocess_csv_deceptive_opinion
  training, validation = train_test_split(read_dataset, train_size=size, shuffle=True, random_state=i, > stratify=read_dataset['one_hot_labels'].to_numpy())
File "/home/[...]/.conda/envs/RC_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2197, in train_test_split
  train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
File "/home/[...]/.conda/envs/RC_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 1793, in split
  y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
File "/home/[...]/.conda/envs/RC_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/[...]/.conda/envs/RC_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 664, in check_array
  allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
File "/home/[...]/.conda/envs/RC_37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 110, in _assert_all_finite
  if _object_dtype_isnan(X).any():
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
```

The dataset used is available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/deceptive-opinion-spam-corpus?select=deceptive-opinion.csv).

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the value of your `i` variable and `read_dataset['labels'].to_numpy()`?

Comment: `i = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}` that is a set, then `i` is a single int; while `read_dataset['labels'].to_numpy()` is an array of labels 2d, like {[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1], ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by conflicting types, and how `pandas` internally handles lists. **Case 3** reproduces the error, and then shows how to fix it in.

---

**Case 1**: `train_test_split` can handle stratified 2D labels:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-0.328,-0.192,0.260,0.408,0.356,0.472,-0.328,-0.184,-0.440,-0.312,0.348,0.432,0.464,0.532,-0.428,-0.292],[0.323,0.503,0.591,0.499,-0.313,-0.229,-0.213,-0.361,0.451,0.595,0.723,0.675,-0.445,-0.361,-0.317,-0.449]]).T
y = np.array([[0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1,1], [0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1,1]])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=0)

print(X_train)
print(y_train)
# [[ 0.408  0.499]
#  ...
#  [ 0.464 -0.445]]
# [[0 1]
#  ...
#  [1 0]]
```

---

**Case 2**: Similar example with a pandas data frame:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

read_data = pd.DataFrame({
   'x0': [-0.328,-0.192,0.260,0.408,0.356,0.472,-0.328,-0.184,-0.440,-0.312,0.348,0.432,0.464,0.532,-0.428,-0.292],
   'x1': [0.323,0.503,0.591,0.499,-0.313,-0.229,-0.213,-0.361,0.451,0.595,0.723,0.675,-0.445,-0.361,-0.317,-0.449],
   'y': [[0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1,1], [0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1,1]],
})

train, test = train_test_split(read_data, train_size=0.8, stratify=read_data['y'], random_state=0)
print(train)
print(test)
#        x0     x1       y
# 3   0.408  0.499  [0, 1]
# 1  -0.192  0.503  [0, 0]
# ...
# 12  0.464 -0.445  [1, 0]
#        x0     x1       y
# 5   0.472 -0.229  [1, 0]
# 15 -0.292 -0.449  [1, 1]
# 11  0.432  0.675  [0, 1]
# 0  -0.328  0.323  [0, 0]
```

**Case 3**: (where the troubles begin)

Here is a minimal example reproducing the `AttributeError` from the question:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

read_data = pd.DataFrame({
   'x0': [-0.328,-0.192,0.260,0.408,0.356,0.472,-0.328,-0.184,-0.440,-0.312,0.348,0.432,0.464,0.532,-0.428,-0.292],
   'x1': [0.323,0.503,0.591,0.499,-0.313,-0.229,-0.213,-0.361,0.451,0.595,0.723,0.675,-0.445,-0.361,-0.317,-0.449],
   'y':  [[0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1,1], [0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,0], [1,0], [1,1], [1,1]],
})

read_data['y_new'] = list(np.array([value for value in read_data['y'].values]))
read_data = read_data.drop(['y'], axis=1)

train, test = train_test_split(read_data, train_size=0.8, stratify=read_data['y_new'], random_state=0)
```

Here, each value in the column `y_new` will be a `numpy.ndarray`:

```py
>>> type(read_data['y_new'][0])
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**How to solve**:

The most direct way would be to ensure values in the `y_new` column are lists, such as by changing the line to:

```py
read_data['y_new'] = [value for value in read_data['y'].values]
```

In the example posted with the question, this would be equivalent to changing to these lines:

```py
read_dataset['one_hot_labels'] = list(read_dataset[list(read_dataset.columns[:2])].values.tolist())
read_dataset = read_dataset.drop(['deceptive', 'polarity'], axis=1)
```